# Reqular Expression Query

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

string x= "Search Results: 1 - 20 of 1,312,224 for your search criteria" .

Need to verify it contains "Search Results: 1 - 20 of (X) for your search criteria"          and (x) can be any numbers

Comment: Can you clarify the { and } and the quotes? It's kinda hard to distinguish as it is with italics

Comment: escape asterisks with a backslash to prevent them becoming italics or bold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code

```
var r = new Regex(@"Search Results: 1 - 20 of [0-9,]+ for your search criteria");
if (r.IsMatch(x)) {
  // yes, match, do your stuff
}
```

Comment: that would only match one digit and a comma, but not '24,' for example.

Comment: What about the +? How many digits would you like that to match? I hope they match 1 or more of the preceding pattern.

Comment: I need to match the string and not the digit ..Digit can be any

Comment: much more simple than mine :)

Comment: If i need to search for @"Search Results: 1 - 20 of ([\d,]+) for (x)" where x can be any computer or laptop or desktop

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"Search Results: 1 - 20 of ([\d,]+) for your search criteria");
```

Comment: If i need to search for @"Search Results: 1 - 20 of ([\d,]+) for (x)" where x can be any computer  or laptop or desktop

Comment: Regex rgx = new Regex(@"Search Results: 1 - 20 of ([\d,]+) for (\w+)" ) works

Answer (score 1):

`Search Results: 1 - 20 of ([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+ for your search criteria`